# What is the difference between model.training = False and model.param.require_grad = False

Tags: pytorch

What is the difference between these two:

```
model.training = False
```

and

```
for param in model.parameters():
    param.require_grad = False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`model.training = False` sets the module in evaluation mode, i.e.,

```
if model.training == True:
    # Train mode
if model.training == False:
    # Evaluation mode
```

So, effectively layers like dropout, batchnorm etc. which behave different on the train and test procedures know what is going on and hence can behave accordingly.

while

```
for param in model.parameters():
    param.require_grad = False
```

freeze the layers so that these layers are not trainable.

The basic idea is that all models have a function model.children() which returns it’s layers. Within each layer, there are parameters (or weights), which can be obtained using .param() on any children (i.e. layer). Now, every parameter has an attribute called `requires_grad` which is by default True. True means it will be backpropagrated and hence to freeze a layer you need to set requires_grad to False for all parameters of a layer.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It's very helpful. Can I summary your explanation to: in param.require_grad = False, the model will use random drop out, but in model.training == False, it will not. Is that correct?

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, please accept it. Thanks.

Comment: In random dropout, we drops out units randomly from the neural network. But, what we are doing here is setting every parameters(weights) or parameters  we want, to not participate in the back-propagation(in the calculation of gradient). It looks like random but actually it isn't. And, agree with your later part as model will not use dropout during evaluation mode.